# Django - tests.py already exists, overlaying a project or app into an existing directory won't replace conflicting files

Tags: django

In my project I'm using Django 1.9. I started this project on older version of Django. After update everything works fine. But now I need to install new app but i can't. When i try to do this i get an error:
`CommandError: /var/www/myproject/myapp/tests.py already exists, overlaying a project or app into an existing directory won't replace conflicting files`.

After that i tried to record my app in `INSTALLED_APPS`, and then i go an error: `ImportError: No module named myapp`.
Here is full traceback of this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named myapp
```

So delete django using pip, and then install again. But i have still the same problem.

At the first time my Installed Apps looks like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'firstapp',
    'secondapp',
    'thirdapp',
)
```

but after Django updating i change:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'firstapp',
    'secondapp',
    'thirdapp',
]
```

Here is layout files of my project:

```
project
    ├── firstapp
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── views.py
    │   ├── forms.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    ├── secondapp
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── views.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    ├── thirdapp
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── views.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    ├── project
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   ├── wsgi.py
    ├── manage.py
```

Comment: What is the layout of your project files, and the value of your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?

Comment: @Alasdair i'm already edit my post

Comment: I can't spot the problem, but that could be because you are using made up names like `myapp`, `firstapp` and `secondapp`.

Comment: @Alasdair here is the link to my project files http://imgur.com/a/toxj9 , i try to create an app in other project and i have the same error, then i try to create the new project and i have this one error: `CommandError: /var/www/testdjangoproject/manage.py already exists, overlaying a project or app into an existing directory won't replace conflicting files`. I call projects with different name and still the same

Comment: Could you try deleting the myapp folder, then running `./manage.py startapp myapp` again? Is your `manage.py` from a very old version of Django. Apart from that, I don't have any other ideas. Hope you manage to find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You surely have fixed your issue by now, but I wanted to put a fix up for anyone else that comes across this.

I had the same issue (also caused after an upgrade to 1.9), and found that I couldn't even run `django-admin startproject` without a similar error when using the same virtualenv.

I created a new virtualenv and then ran `pip install -r requirements.txt` to load all the project's required packages. I could then create apps without a problem.

I compared the two virtualenv site-packages directories, but saw no glaring differences. Either way, this worked to fix my issue.